# Do flashbacks break up short stories too much?

Tags: short-story, flashback

Recently, I wrote a short story that contains a flashback in the middle that was used to explain a major plot point in the story. Does a significant scene set as a flashback break up the flow of a short story (usually considered to be somewhere between 1,000 and 15,000 words, depending on who is asked), and if so, why?

Answer (score 5):

It's all about context. I don't think there's a blanket answer. *An Occurrence at Owl Creek Bridge* is, in a sense, a flashback in the middle of the story, but it works exquisitely.

Comment: Even short stories need structure (more so, possibly). So it can work in exactly the same way as for a longer story.

Comment: The flashback in the Bierce piece you mentioned is actually an inside-out [framing device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_device) for the real action of the story. I wouldn't really call it a flashback, either, since it's more of a dream sequence — part memory, part fantasy.

Comment: I agree, which is why I wrote "in a sense." My point was that there's no hard-and-fast rule; it depends on the story.